# Upload File to Google Cloud Storage Bucket Sub Directory using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python

I have successfully implemented the python function to upload  a file to Google Cloud Storage bucket but I want to add it to a sub-directory (folder) in the bucket and when I try to add it to the bucket name the code fails to find the folder.

Thanks!

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name +"/folderName") #I tried to add my folder here
  blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

  print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
    source_file_name,
    destination_blob_name))
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're adding the "folder" in the wrong place. Note that Google Cloud Storage doesn't have real folders or directories (see [Object name considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations)).

A simulated directory is really just an object with a prefix in its name. For example, rather than what you have right now:

- bucket = bucket/folderName
- object = objectname

You'll instead want:

- bucket = bucket
- object = folderName/objectname

In the case of your code, I think this should work:

```
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob("folderName/" + destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried to implement it I got the following error:

blob.upload_from_filename("logFiles/" + source_file_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 988, in upload_from_filename with open(filename, 'rb') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logFiles/serverLog.csv.gz'

Comment: Presumably, you don't have a file in your current working directory named "logFiles/serverLog.csv.gz". Try specifying its absolute local filename?

Comment: Sorry, I put the prefix on the wrong variable. Try it now.

Comment: Really useful answer, thanks for this. This is probably the most relevant bit of documentation on object naming:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations

Comment: GCS foldernames don't start with "/". It's just folderName/folderName/fileName